# Proof verification: Linearly independent vectors are an open subset

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space of dimension $n < \infty$, where $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{C}$. Let $V^r$ be the set of $r$-tuples of vectors from $V$ where $1 \leq r \leq n$ and denote by $V_0^r$ the subset of $r$-tuples of linearly independent vectors in $V^r$.

I have to prove that $V_0^r$ is an open subset. I have seen proofs of this using the norm. However, I'd like to use a different approach:

We can naturally identify $V^n$ with $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{K})$ by writing a tuple as a matrix where the vectors are the columns of the matrix. Since $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{K}) \cong \mathbb{K}^{n^2}$ and as $V^r$ is equipped with the product topology (as far as I can tell from the exercise) and thus $V^n \cong \mathbb{K}^{n^2}$, I concluded that $V^n \cong M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{K})$.

It is also clear that $V_0^n \cong GL_n(\mathbb{K})$, the latter being an open subset of $M_{n \times n }(\mathbb{K})$ as $GL_n(\mathbb{K}) = \det^{-1}(\mathbb{K} - 0)$. Let $\pi_r: V^n \to V^r$ denote the projection on the first $r$ coordinates. In particular, $\pi_r$ is an open map for any $1 \leq r \leq n$. Since we can complete any $r$-tuple of linearly independent vectors in $V$ to a basis, we have the following equation:
$$
V_0^r = \pi_r(V_0^n),
$$
which proves that $V_0^r$ is indeed an open set.

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: It seems correct to(me my topology classes are way behind me). However, it seems complicated. Fix a basis of $V$. If $\alpha\in V^r$, we can write the corresponding $r\times n$ matrix $M_\alpha$. If $I$ is a subset of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with $r$ elements, let $f_I:V^r\to \mathbb{K}$ which send $r$ vectors to the  minor of $M_\alpha$ of size $r$ constructed by selecting the lines of $M_\alpha$ whose indices lie in $I$. This map is continuous since its polynomial in the coordinates of the vectors of the $r$-uple. Now $V_0^r$ is  the union of the open sets $f_I^{-1}(\mathbb{K}^\times)$.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Do you mean by _writing the corresponding $r \times n$ matrix_ that you write the vectors in $\alpha$ into the lines of a matrix?

Comment: Sorry, it's a $n\times r$ matrix. You write the vectors into columns.